# 【Rails】scopeの委譲のやり方を教えて下さい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

e.g)

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :under_100 -> { where(id < 100 ) }
end

class B 
  has_one :a
  # under_100を使いたい
end
```

railsのscopeをdelegateなどを使って委譲させる方法はありますか？？
moduleを使わないと難しいですかね。

Answer (score 1):

mergeを使うと関連先のscopeを使うことができます。

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :a
  scope :a_under_100, -> { joins(:a).merge(A.under_100) }
end

# 関連するAのidが100以下であるBのリストが返る
B.a_under_100
```

が、ちょっと情報が少ないので、やりたいことがこれで合っているか確信がありません。
もし違っていたら、具体的なデータベースの値と期待する結果の例を追記してください。